# How do I Save an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Configuration Without Errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting this error message when I try to save my current environment configuration:

```
Error in creating saved configuration for environment
Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:instances', OptionName: 'InstanceTypes'): Your selected instance types (t3.micro) aren't available in your selected VPC Subnets. t3.micro is available in [us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1f]. Please check your VPC Subnets.
```

I didn't select any instance type of t3. My config uses t2.micro, t2.small. The subnets are all in us-east-1.

Any idea on how to fix this?